# Tobit model with R

Tags: r, tobit-regression

Does anybody know where to find good application and examples (besides the manual and the book applied econometrics with R) using the tobit model with the packages AER?

#### Edit

I'm searching for a command to compute the marginal effects for y (not for the latent variable y*). It seems to be $\phi(x\beta/\sigma)\beta$, where $\phi$ is the std.normal cumulative distribution function. But how can I compute those effects with R?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not in the package, just write your own command. If your regression is reg <- tobit(y~x) then the vector of effects should be

```
pnorm(x%*%reg$coef[-1]/reg$scale)%*%reg$coef[-1].
```

Comment: Did you miss some t()? Just get some  `non-conformable arguments` when I try to it with the example data provided by `AER::tobit`. Would you mind giving it a try with the example dataset?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue (“`non-conformable arguments`”) that @hans0l0 mentioned in comment above. I think I have resolved this, and will try to explain here.

First, there is an error in the equation in the original post. It should be $ϕ(xβ/σ)β_j$—i.e., there is a subscript after the second $β$ but not after the first. In a Tobit model, the marginal effect of a variable $x_j$ is determined not only by the coefficient of that particular variable (the $β_j$); an adjustment factor is also required that gets calculated from the values of other variables in the model (the $ϕ(xβ/σ)$).

From Wooldridge 2006 (p. 598):

> The adjustment factor… depends on a linear function of $x$, $xβ/σ = (β_0 + β_1x_1 + … + β_kx_k)/σ$. It can be shown that the adjustment factor is strictly between zero and one.

This adjustment factor means that we have to make a choice about the values of the other variables in the model: “we must plug in values for the x<sub>j</sub>, usually the mean values or other interesting values” (Wooldridge 2006, p598). So generally this would be the mean, but it could also be the median, the top/bottom quartile, or anything else. This relates to why @hans0l0 and I were getting the “`non-conformable argument`” errors when we were using Alex’s code above: the “`x`” in that code will be a vector when what we need is a single value for the variable (mean / median / etc). I believe there is also another error in the code above in that it excludes the intercept value from the adjustment term (with the `[-1]` script after the first use of `reg$coef`). My understanding of this (but I’m happy to be corrected) is that the adjustment term should include the intercept (the $β_0$ from above).

That all said, here is an example using the dataset from `AER::tobit (“Affairs”)`:

```
## Using the same model and data as in the Tobit help file
## NB: I have added the “x=TRUE” command so the model saves the x values

> fm.tobit <- tobit(affairs ~ age + yearsmarried + religiousness + occupation + rating,
                    data = Affairs, x=TRUE)
> fm.tobit$coef
(Intercept)  age         yearsmarried  religiousness  occupation  rating 
8.1741974    -0.1793326  0.5541418     -1.6862205     0.3260532   -2.2849727

> fm.tobit$scale
[1] 8.24708 

## the vector of marginal effects (at mean values and for y > 0) should be as follows.
## note the [-1] used to remove the intercept term from the final vector, 
##  but not from within the adjustment term. 

> pnorm(sum(apply(fm.tobit$x,2,FUN=mean) * fm.tobit$coef)/fm.tobit$scale) * 
  fm.tobit$coef[-1]
  age        yearsmarried  religiousness  occupation  rating 
  -0.041921  0.1295365     -0.394172      0.076218    -0.534137
```

Important to reiterate: these are marginal effects only in the cases where y is positive (i.e. at least one affair has happened) and at the mean values of all of the explanatory variables.

If somebody would like to check those results using a program with a built-in marginal effects tool for Tobit models, I would be curious to see the comparison. Any comments and corrections will be very appreciated.

**Reference**:
Wooldridge, Jeffrey M. 2006. Introductory Econometrics: A Modern Approach. Thomson South-Western. 3rd Edition.

Comment: Thanks for this contribution. Welcome to CV. I hope we'll see more.

Comment: In reaction to your last paragraph, R's package {censReg} and the functions censReg() combined with margEff.censReg() produce the same results as your calculation, plus some statistical inference  output.